# Compare several strings in an if statement

Tags: c#

Is there a better way to do this?

```
var line = sr.ReadLine();
string[] values = line.Split(';');

if (d == "abc"|| d == "def"|| d == "ghi")
    {

    }
```

Since I seemed to get an error message regarding this if statement I added && false to every comparison and replaced the == with the equals method, both without positive results, but this turned out irrelevant.

Comment: You don't need that `?? false` - `string.Equals` never returns a `null`

Comment: Why are you using the null coalescing operator (`??`) with things that can't be null (the `bool` result of `Equals`)?  It's only complaining about the "last" one because the syntax is so incorrect it's doing the best it can.  But remove the last one and it'll just complain about the new last one.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll update that. It was one of my attempts at getting rid of the error message. I'll add that as well.

Comment: I can't parse your intent, but it seems to me you just want `d == "abc" || d == "def" || d == "ghi"`.  Possibly you want the inverse of that; hard to say.

Comment: If I try `if (d.Equals("abc") ?? false)`, I get a compiler error "CS0019 Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'bool' " - showing that that `?? false` is not required and even wrong. Always try and make sense of error messages you get! (and include them in your question here)

Comment: Yes that is excactly what I try to reach: if(d == "abc" || d == "def" || d == "ghi"). But this returns the error "Operator || cannot be applied to operands of types bool and bool"

Comment: `if (d=="abc"|| d=="def" || d=="ghi")` works for me

Comment: @Miles Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have. Also add the full complete error message you get. Additionally add a screenshot of the full complete error message you get to your question as well.

Comment: @Miles You have to show the full source code and the full error message you get, otherwise we can't help or check what the problem is. There is no problem in using `==` on strings and `||` and `&&` on boolean values/expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend this

1. notice that if d is null no exception is throw
2. And also you can extend your list for other compare strings if necessary
3. You do not need to write a large if statement with comparing d for each string

   ```
   string d = values[10];
   var list = new List<string>() { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
   if (!list.Contains(d))
   {

   }
   ```

Comment: You can replace the list by a `HashSet` to have a O(1) `Contains()`.